# Expectation of independent normal rv

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Given $X_j=\sum_{k=1}^n c_{j,k}Y_k$, where $c$ is a matrix of constants and $Y$ the independent standard normal rv's, we need the $E[X_j|X_k]$.

I have used the following approach. Not sure if this is the right way to go about.
Since they are independent, I have used $E[X_j|X_k] = E[X_j]$ since $E[Y_j]=0$ and hence $E[X_j|X_k]=0$.

Comment: Independence of the $Y_k$ does not imply independence of the $X_j$.

Comment: How about not using $k$ as the index variable in the summation, given that you are interested in computing $E[X_j | X_k]$

Answer (score 1):

$X_j$ and $X_k$ are not indepndent.

There is a well known result which says that $E(X_j|X_k)=cX_k$ for some constant $c$. [This is a property of jointly normal random variables with mean $0$]. We can compute $c$ by mutiplying both sides by $X_k$ and taking  expecation. Thus $c=\frac {EX_jX_k} {EX_k^{2}}$. Can you compute $EX_jX_k$ and $EX_k^{2}$?

Comment: How does one compute Var[Xj|Xk] ?

Comment: @Byzantine The exists $a$ such that $Z=X_j-aX_k$ and $X_k$ are independent. (Make their covariance $0$). Then write $X_j^{2}$ in terms of $Z$ and $X_k$.

Comment: I am still not sure why I have to compute C. [|] will be a formula right ? same for Var[Xj|Xk].Sorry I am a noob learning stats using stack exchange questions . Can you please give a full answer